# Working with Java beans and Servlet values dynamically

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dynamic, javabeans

I have a table that sends a form post of 5 input text with values to servlet. In servlet I get the values and set them into bean class, and the sum that I set it too to bean class as sum.Then I get the values and the sum on the jsp table.The problem, is that now Im creating a button that when I click, I insert a row after the last row, and I want to keep the values too with the sum, How can I do it?

This is my jsp that send the form to Servlet: `Test.jsp`

```html
<jsp:useBean id="helloBean" scope="request" class="user.HelloBean" />
<form method="post" action="Servlet">
    <table id= "sum_table">
        <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="Test1" maxlength=25></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="${helloBean.sum}" maxlength=3 readonly="readonly"></td>
            <c:forEach items="${helloBean.values}" var="item">
                <td><input type="text" id="val" name="values" value="${item}" maxlength=2/></td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <p><input type="submit"/></p>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="+"/>
</form>
```

Now I got the values on servlet, calculate the sum and send them to java bean: `Servlet.java`

```
HelloBean hello  = new HelloBean();
String[] values = request.getParameterValues("values");

if (values == null) {
    values = new String[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        values[i]= "0";
    }
}

Integer sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    hello.setSum(sum = sum + Integer.valueOf(values[i]));
    hello.setValues(values);
}   

request.setAttribute("helloBean", hello);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/Test.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And this is my Bean Class: `HelloBean.java`

```
public class HelloBean {
    String[] values;
    Integer sum;

    public Integer getSuma() {return sum;}
    public void setSum(Integer integer) {this.sum = integer;}
    public String[] getValues() {return values;}
    public void setValues(String[] val) {this.values = val;}
}
```

This is how I add a new row:

```javascript
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
    var row = $("#sum_table tbody > tr:last"),
        newRow = row.clone(true);
    newRow.find("input").each(function () {
        var num = +(this.id.match(/\d+$/) || [0])[0] + 1;
        this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + num;
        this.name = this.id;
    });
    newRow.insertAfter(row);
    return false;
});
```

Thank You in Advance!

Comment: The whole question is confusing because you're concentrating way too much on the JSP/Servlet side, while your concrete problem is actually in the JavaScript side. What exactly do you want? Solve this in JS, or drop the whole JS approach and go for a pure JSP/Servlet approach to add a new row? That said, I would also spend a bit more effort in finding good learning resources and make sure that you don't learn JSP, Servlet and HTML via 20 year old resources. The `<jsp:useBean>` and those uppercased HTML tags/attributes and unquoted attribute values are way too 1990-2000.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you very much for telling me about the age of the code I am using.I will try to find new resources.I'm a bit lose about where to do the operation.Well, now I have the sum of one row and the total.I do the calc inside the servlet side, and asign the values to the bean.But I want to in jsp add more rows with one button and calculate one total for every row.I can do it with one, but I dont know how to add more.

Comment: In JSP/Servlet or in HTML/JS? Your current code adds one more row using HTML/JS, not using JSP/Servlet. Please, you should as a starting web developer already understand that JSP/Servlet code runs in webserver and procuces HTML/JS code which get sent from webserver to webbrowser who in turn runs HTML/JS code. Rightclick page in webbrowser and view source and so on. That's what the webbrowser has retrieved and is executing. You should not see any single line of JSP/Servlet code over there.

Comment: @BalusC Then is in HTML/JS but I'm a bit lost on how to do it. Because I dont know really what I need to do that.

Comment: I'd suggest using knockout.js and doing the adding client-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put a check on the value of `sum` in JSP page and based on its value add new row.

#### pseudo code:

```
 if sum is not null then
     add a new row in JSP
```

When page is loaded first time the value of the `sum` will be `null` and when redirected by servlet the value is populated and the `sum` will not be `null` and a new row is automatically created in the JSP page.

---

It should be like this and keep in mind the [integer overflow problem](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6255/int-overflow-check-in-java).

```
int sum=0;
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + Integer.valueOf(values[i]);
}
hello.setValues(values);
hello.setSum(sum);
```

It should look like in JSP:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="Test1" maxlength="25"/></td>
        <c:forEach items="${helloBean.values}" var="item">
            <td><input type="text" name="values" value="${item}" maxlength="2"/></td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
    <c:if test="${helloBean.sum != null}">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" value="${helloBean.sum}" maxlength="3" readonly="readonly"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:if>
```

---

Some points:

- ID must be unique in the whole page. Multiple `input` components are created with the same id `val` in the loop.
- Use double quotes around the attribute values of the each tag. Is it typo?
- property `sum` is not readable on type `user.HelloBean` because there is no `getSum()` method in class.

Comment: But this will be able to increase rows and when you submit will show the values ​​of each row and the corresponding sum?

Comment: Sorry not clear to me. What I want to say is that when page is refreshed and just one new row is added based on its value.

Comment: Or simply create one more variable in your class and use hidden input field in JSP to keep the value of last sum.

Comment: Maybe you understand me wrong, Sorry for my explanation.If I write the 5 values and click submit it show me the values with the sum.But If i want to add a new row, and put values to sum it too and show them under the first row, they dissapear.I have tried many ways but I do not understand.I'm a little lost :/

Comment: put a check just before `</table>` as used in pseudo code to add a new row in the last.

Comment: why are you setting `hello.setSum()` in loop? Simply put it ouside the loop in the end and set the `sum`. Move `hello.setValues(values);` outside the loop as well. In loop just add the values and update `sum` .

Comment: I dont know whats wrong, but the values of the other row didnt keep. I updated with the code to add new row.

Comment: I have update my post. There is no need to add the new row based using JQuery.

Comment: But if I dont use the add row, How can I add a new row?

Comment: Because I want to add 1 total for every row that I add with the button.

Comment: What do you mean? TT Im a bit lose about how can I increment every value to set a new row and increment the total too..

Answer (score 1):

Don't need the Bean class

### You can add keyup event for input

```
<form method="post" action="Servlet">
<table id= "sum_table">
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td class="test"><input type="text" name="test" value="Test1" maxlength=25></td>
        <td class="sum"><input type="text" name="sum" value="" maxlength=3 readonly="readonly"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mark1" value="" maxlength=2 ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mark2" value="" maxlength=2 ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mark3" value="" maxlength=2 ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mark4" value="" maxlength=2 ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mark5" value="" maxlength=2 ></td>           

    </tr>
</table>

<p><input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/></p>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="+"/>
```

```
        <script>
        $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
            var row = $("#sum_table tbody > tr:last"),
                newRow = row.clone(true);
            newRow.find("input").each(function () {
                var num = +(this.id.match(/\d+$/) || [0])[0] + 1;
                this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + num;
                this.name = this.id;
            });
            newRow.insertAfter(row);
            return false;
        });

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            $("#sum_table tbody tr").each(function() {
                var row_total = 0; 
                $("td:not('.test'), td:not('.sum') input:text",this).each(function() {
                    var val =$.trim($(this).val());  
                    //console.log('val='+val);
                    if(val!="" && !isNaN(val))
                   row_total += Number(val);
                }); 
                console.log('row_total='+row_total);
                $(".sum :input:text",this).val(row_total);
            });
        });

    </script>
```

-------------------SERVLET--------------

```
 String[] test = request.getParameterValues("test");
 String[] sum = request.getParameterValues("sum");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way without using javascript for adding new row, if it helps you.

1) - Add name to the add button

```
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" ***name="addrow"*** value="+"/>
```

2) - At Servlet side check if add button is clicked

```
if (request.getParameter("addrow") != null){
  request.setAttribute("addRow","yes");
}
```

3) - At Jsp side add below your for loop

```
<c:if test="${not empty request.addRow}">
   <td><input type="text" id="val" name="values" value="" maxlength=2/></td>
</c:if>
```

This will add new emty text field whenever you click on the button. 
NOTE: I did not test this code.

Comment: It add me correctly the line, but when I put the values and click calc, then It only show me one line.

Comment: @devtreat - Can you explain more on "it shows me only one line".

Comment: Because, when I click on + It adds one row more, but when I put values on the new row and click on submit, the row dissapear and the values too. Only keep me the sum and values of first row.

Comment: No. Added values should not disappear. It means you are not setting the values back in your servlet code. Add println statements and figure out where you are doing wrong. I gave you general idea how to do it. Now you have to figure out from your errors

Comment: My servlet is like the Braj answer. I think that its ok.

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace with your input code I added "values[]" instead of "values"

You can use it as array and also set keys into it

```
<input type="text" id="val" name="values[]" value="${item}" maxlength=2/>
```